# .NET Core 1.0 -- насколько готов к использованию?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

27 июня вышла версия .NET Core 1.0 и ряд сопутствующих библиотек.

Вопросы в следующем:

Насколько .NET Core в текущем состоянии готов для использования в качестве основы веб-приложений? Имеет ли смысл переходить на него сейчас, или пока только изучать?

Насколько стабилен .NET Core? Не слишком ли он "сырой" для промышленных применений?

Какие проблемы / "подводные камни" есть в нём сейчас, что мешает больше всего?

Какие части API .NET Framework НЕ реализованы в .NET Core? Какие есть новые API, отсутствующие в .NET Framework?

P.S. Пока нашёл только вот такой (частичный) ответ, по состоянию на апрель: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422152/is-net-core-1-0-ready-to-be-used-on-a-full-scale-production-site-yet

Comment: По-моему, вопрос сформулирован вполне понятно и ответ на него может быть дан. Я хотел бы назначить за этот вопрос награду, но не могу поскольку вопрос был закрыт.

Comment: Наверное, стоит оставить комментарий здесь, а не на мете: вопрос закрыли из-за слишком пространной формулировки в первой части - нельзя за кого-то решить, подходит ли ему новая технология, не зная контекста. Т.е. можно обосновать применимость фреймворка в конкретном случае, но никак нельзя обосновать его "готовность". Он зарелижен - значит, формально, готов к живому применению. Подойдет ли он вам - неизвестно. Нужно ли переходить на него лично вам - неизвестно.

Comment: Есть рабочий проект на коре. Все нормально, сам по себе он не доставляет никаких проблем. Есть проблемы с ЕФ кор, начиная от неявных нововведений, о которых узнаешь позже, заканчивая не реализованными частями. Если бы я начинал проект сейчас я бы начинал его на коре, и очень внимательно присмотрелся к использованию ЕФ 6.

Answer (score -3):

Нисколько не готов - потому что дело даже не в самой MS. 
А поддержат ли эту платформу другие облака кроме Azure.

Comment: Вы считаете что .NET Core только в облаке можно использовать?

Comment: Ну а где же еще? По моему ради этого все и затевалось.